# Using com assemblies without registry in docker

Tags: docker, sdk, com, registry

I am trying to run an application in a docker container which uses the 'microsoft/aspnetcore' image.
(It is not possible to get the 'microsoft/windowsservercore' or 'microsoft/nanoserver' image, because docker is installed on linux.)

This application should use assemblies from an SDK. However as you can imagine, I cannot install this SDK on the microsoft/aspnetcore and I presume this image has got no registry/windows services?

**This leads me to my question;**
What is the best way to include the assemblies and bypass the need for the registry to find these assemblies?
(It currently generates a 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' because the classes/assemblies are not registered)

Comment: With ASP.NET Core, your problem can not be solved yet, but [such a project](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/) is ongoing. There is a possibility of solving in the future.

Comment: @kunif It is not about existing .net core that needs to be ported. It is about assemblies in an SDK that needs to be located without registry functionality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use Microsoft's Registration-Free COM. It's possible to hack something together yourself, but Microsoft has already provided a framework for this.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/registration-free-com-interop
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375134(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This seems to work. However up until it seems to use 'custom' registry values which are not defined in the Assembly Manifests (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374219(v=vs.85).aspx). Do you also know a solution for this?